# aDropdown menu is overlapping the navbar

Tags: css, tailwind-css

```
  import React, { useEffect, useState,CSSProperties } from "react";
    import img from "../../../public/images/home/desktop/headphone-hero-image.png"
    import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
    import AliceCarousel from 'react-alice-carousel';
    import 'react-alice-carousel/lib/alice-carousel.css';
    import axios from "axios"
    import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
    
    import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
    export default function Product()
    
    {
    
    
    ///
    const[value,setvalue]=useState()
    const [done, setDone] = useState(undefined);
    
    const handleDragStart = (e) => e.preventDefault();
    const options = [
    'one', 'two', 'three'
    ];
    
    const defaultOption = options[0];
    //
    const items = [
    <img src={img} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
    <img src={img} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
    <img src={img} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
    ];
    
    
    ///////
    const[data,setdata]=useState({})
    const { id } = useParams();
    
    useEffect(()=>{
    const getdata=async ()=>{
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/product/find/${id}`)
    setdata(response.data.exist)
    console.log(data)
    }
    getdata();
    },[id])
    
    
    return(
    <div className="">
    
    <div className=" pt-28 flex">
    <div className="w-[50%] -z-10 flex flex-col justify-center items-center mx-auto lg:flex-row-reverse">
    <h1 className=" font-extrabold text-6xl lg:text-7xl" >{data.name}</h1>
    
    <AliceCarousel mouseTracking items={items} />
    
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
   <div className="">
  <div className="flex  flex-row  justify-evenly items-center mx-3 my-5 py-4 flex-wrap ">
    <p>Select qty:</p>
    <Dropdown
      options={options}
      /*onChange={this._onSelect}*/ value={defaultOption}
      placeholder="Select an option"
    />

    <button className=" w-[80%] mt-3 py-2 bg-orange-500 rounded-lg">
      Add to cart
    </button>
  </div>
  <div className=" mx-auto w-[80%]  overflow-auto">
    <p className="break-words font-extralight ">{data.description}</p>
  </div>
</div>;
    </div>
    )
    }
```

wherever i try to scroll the page the dropdown get over the Navbar.I try multiple solution but still its getting over the Navbar.Always this dropdown gets overlapped over the navbar.Tried z index and its not working.I had similar issued with the image i added above but when i add flex to parent div it was solved.Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you provide more code please?

Comment: @underflow hey sorry for late reply.i added the whole code

Comment: We can't reproduce this code, it will be hard to figure out what can be the issue, maybe post a video of what happens when you scroll or create a reproducible example with play.tailwind or codepen/codesandbox/stackblitz.

Comment: @RicardoSilva  Linkt to video  :https://tempclip.com/TFBk1YHpMFhUtHw/watch

Comment: It looks like a z-index issue, try to debug the devtools if there is any z-index set or try to change it.

Comment: @RicardoSilva Tried it not working.Both navbar and other is different component